Keycloak set required actions for user to Configure OTP
How to set required actions for user through keycloak API? I haven't found it in their admin rest API documentation. There is only
PUT /{realm}/users/{userId}/execute-actions-email
but it works through email which does not fit my requirements. I would like to force user to
configure OTP on next login.
Can anyone tell what should be the url after {userId}
I have tried this url
PUT /{realm}/users/{userId}/settings
but this does not work for me.

REST API
PUT /{realm}/users/{userId}
Payload
{
    "id": {user id},
    "username": {user name},
    "email": {user email},
    "emailVerified": false,
    "createdTimestamp": {Epoch & Unix Timestamp},
    "enabled": true,
    "totp": false,
    "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
    "requiredActions": [
        "CONFIGURE_TOTP"
    ],
    "notBefore": 0,
    "access": {
        "manageGroupMembership": true,
        "view": true,
        "mapRoles": true,
        "impersonate": true,
        "manage": true
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "firstName": {first name},
    "lastName": {last name}
}

Example
{
    "id": "0baf6148-01f1-4bad-a781-da1bfd36d234",
    "username": "user1",
    "email": "user1@test.com",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "createdTimestamp": 1731062915931,
    "enabled": true,
    "totp": false,
    "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
    "requiredActions": [
        "CONFIGURE_TOTP"
    ],
    "notBefore": 0,
    "access": {
        "manageGroupMembership": true,
        "view": true,
        "mapRoles": true,
        "impersonate": true,
        "manage": true
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": ""
}

user actions list
VERIFY_EMAIL, UPDATE_PROFILE, CONFIGURE_TOTP, UPDATE_PASSWORD, TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS

Result
When he/she login, show OTP configuration screen.


will this work ?
{
"requiredActions": [
"CONFIGURE_TOTP"
]
}

Yes, PUT is update. it will works https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/latest/rest-api/index.html#UserRepresentation
